# How to avoid redirects when parsing a site?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am parsing a site in python using BF4. All pages except one are parsed without problems. But the problem the page cannot be read due to the fact that after referring to this page it redirects me to main page.
Is some script responsible for this? And how in theory to bypass this redirection?

P.S. I am already authorized on the site

Comment: "BF4" battlefield 4? What are you using to GET the page?

Comment: Please post your code.